# Make `systemd-run` fail gracefully if the unit name already exists?

Tags: systemd

I have found `systemd-run` which allows one to run processes in the background once off ("transient services"). I always specify the service unit name with `--unit $NAME`. But if I have already run the `systemd-run` command and my process is running, then `systemd-run` will fail, with non-zero exit code. Is there anyway to tell `systemd-run` to be more idempotent and not fail in this case?

Currently I'm doing:

```
 systemctl is-active $NAME || systemd-run --unit $NAME $COMMAND
```

Is there a better way?

This is on Ubuntu 18.04, with the current systemd for that (version 237?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**-G, --collect**

Unload the transient unit after it completed, even if it failed. Normally, without this option, all units that ran and failed are kept in memory until the user explicitly resets their failure state with systemctl reset-failed or an equivalent command. On the other hand, units that ran successfully are unloaded immediately. If this option is turned on the "garbage collection" of units is more aggressive, and unloads units regardless if they exited successfully or failed. This option is a shortcut for --property=CollectMode=inactive-or-failed, see the explanation for CollectMode= in systemd.unit(5) for further information.

```
systemd-run --collect --unit $NAME $COMMAND
```

Comment: Note that after unloading the unit (with `--collect` or `systemctl reset-failed` or through rebooting) it cannot be inspected using `systemctl status`, but its logs are still in journal, i.e. a failing transient unit tells us why with `journalctl -u $NAME -e`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way not to fail.

The problem here is that systemd unit names must be unique. If they aren't, then manipulating the units could become ambiguous. For this reason systemd perceives an error if you try to duplicate unit names, and I don't think there is a way to make it think otherwise.

If you could convince `systemd-run` to run the second service with the same name, what would happen if you issue a `systemctl stop` command? Which of the two identically named units should stop? The one you ran first? The last? Both?

Comment: That's good points. I don't want to run the service twice. An option like `--no-start-if-active` or `--reset-failed-unit-name` (to run `systemctl reset-failed $NAME`) would address this issue without starting a second unit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need `--collect` for the unit to be deleted (see answer https://serverfault.com/a/1056478/161855).

```
$ systemctl is-active foo || systemd-run --collect --unit foo sleep 1000
inactive
Running as unit: foo.service
$ systemctl is-active foo || systemd-run --collect --unit foo sleep 1000
active
```

This introduces a slight [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), but is better than nothing, and will not cause `systemd-run` to print an error if the unit is already running.